# How to disable form formGroup?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular4-forms

I need to use something like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="" [disabled]="func(formGroup, cond)">
```

And disable this:

```
    funct(form, cond) {

      if (cond) {
          form.disable();
       }

     }
```

Comment: disabled expects a boolean expression. All your function needs to do is to return true or false. But since it returns cond, all you actually need is `[disabled]="cond"`. OTOH, formGroup expects a FormGroup. `[formGroup]=""` doesn't make sense. All that said, I'm not sure HTML allows disabling a form.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right: HTML forms dont have `disable` attribute, but only form controls. Take a look at [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like suggested by @JB Nizet the disabled expects only a boolean value (true or false).
Upgrade your code with a variable 'cond' and if this is true you disable the form.